# Render problem when using moshi in Jetpack Compose @Preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, moshi

I am trying to parse a fake JSON string to Object using [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) in the @Preview block of Jetpack Compose, and below is my code:

```
@Preview("Post Card")
@Composable
fun PostCardPreview() {

    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val type: Type =
        Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Post::class.java)
    val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter<List<Post>>(type)
    val posts = jsonAdapter.fromJson(fakePostDatas) ?: listOf()

    TestAppTheme {
        Surface {
            PostCard(post = posts[0])
        }
    }
}
```

And I encountered the following problem:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(java.lang.reflect.Type, java.util.Set, java.lang.String)'
    at me.yaoandy107.dribbbleone.model.PostJsonAdapter.<init>(PostJsonAdapter.kt:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters.generatedAdapter(StandardJsonAdapters.java:246)
    at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(StandardJsonAdapters.java:62)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:130)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:64)
    at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.newArrayListAdapter(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:52)
    at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$1.create(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:36)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:130)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:64)
    at me.yaoandy107.dribbbleone.ui.home.PostCardKt.PostCardPreview(PostCard.kt:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableMethod(PreviewUtils.kt:141)
    at 
    ......
```

I am very new in Jetpack Compose, am I using it in the wrong way? Or is it just can't use the codegen class in the @Preview?

Comment: "Or is it just can't use the codegen class in the @Preview?" -- that might well be the direct problem. More generally... I would argue that a composable, particularly one designed for use with `@Preview`, should not be parsing data. It should receive already-parsed data as function parameters, and something else (e.g., viewmodel or repository) would be responsible for parsing your data.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your comment and suggestion! I have modified it to already-parsed data. The reason I want to parse the JSON in my preview is that creating an instance of my data class should give too many parameters, so I just kind of lazy to do so.

Comment: @CommonsWare samples for Compose indicate that for preview purposes it's ok to do some blocking operations to get data, so maybe it shouldn't be a bad idea to use some JSON response parsed on the fly…

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/2e2a01e25c3f0b1581efd1bc84611a300d4e950f/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/article/ArticleScreen.kt#L290

Comment: I've had this too ... while it makes sense that you can avoid it by not parsing in the @Preview, it's still unclear to me exactly why it's happening, and it would be helpful to understand!